# Why can't Spark properly load columns from HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below I provide my schema and the code that I use to read from partitions in hdfs.

An example of a partition could be this path: `/home/maria_dev/data/key=key/date=19 jan` (and of course inside this folder there's a csv file that contains `cnt`)

So, the data I have is partitioned by `key` and `date` columns.

When I read it like below the columns are not properly read, so `cnt` gets read into `date` and vice versa.

How can I resolve this?

```scala
private val tweetSchema = new StructType(Array(
    StructField("date", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("key", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("cnt", IntegerType, nullable = true)
  ))

// basePath example: /home/maria_dev/data
// path example: /home/maria_dev/data/key=key/data=19 jan
private def loadDF(basePath: String, path: String, format: String): DataFrame = {
    val df = spark.read
      .schema(tweetSchema)
      .format(format)
      .option("basePath", basePath)
      .load(path)
    df
}
```

I tried changing their order in the schema from `(date, key, cnt)` to `(cnt, key, date)` but it does not help.

My problem is that when I call `union`, it appends 2 dataframes:

- df1: `{(key: 1, date: 2)}`
- df2: `{(date: 3, key: 4)}`

into the final dataframe like this: `{(key: 1, date: 2), (date: 3, key: 4)}`. As you can see, the columns are messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that everything was read properly.

So, now, instead of doing `df1.union(df2)`, I do `df1.select("key", "date").union(df2.select("key", "date"))` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The schema should be in the following order:

- Columns present in the data files as such - in case of CSV in the natural order from left to right.
- Columns used with partitioning in the same order as defined by the directory structure.

So in your case the correct order will be:

```scala
new StructType(Array(
  StructField("cnt", IntegerType, nullable = true),
  StructField("key", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("date", StringType, nullable = true)
))
```